# Is there a way to get the count of Samplers present in entire Jmeter plan without using any reports?

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Is there a way to get the count of unique Samplers executed in entire Jmeter plan without using any reports?

I want to display the count of executed samplers uniquely (Eg: If there are total 10 samplers present and they are execute using loop of 2 then I want the result as 10 and not 20).

My requirement is just to show the count of Samplers used in JMeter test plan.

Note: I am using maven project architecture for my Tests.

Any help will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can count for example all the enabled [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers in the test plan using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language. The number will be written to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

```
def engine = engine = ctx.getEngine()
def testPlan = engine.test

def samplerSearch = new org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass<>(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.class)
testPlan.traverse(samplerSearch)
counter = samplerSearch.getSearchResults()
log.info('Found ' + counter.size() + ' samplers in test plan')
```

Demo:

[image]